# Disposing the JFrame of another class

Tags: java, swing

So I've been developing a small game for a school project (just started with Swing GUI), and I have a class called Background that stays open the whole time unless the resolution is changed in a settings menu.

In the settings menu, I create a new instance of the Background class, with the new resolution.

Problem is, I'm not sure how to *dispose of the old Background instance* when doing so.

Here is the **Background class**:

```
package hangman;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Background extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private int width = 1920;
    private int height = 1080;
    private String resolution;
    private String screenSize;

    public Background(String constrScreenSize) {
        initComponents();
        screenSize = constrScreenSize;
        getDefaultRes();

        if(screenSize.equals("Fullscreen")) {
            setToFullscreen();
        }
        else {
            setToWindowed();
        }
    }

    public Background(String constrScreenSize, String constrResolution) {
        initComponents();
        screenSize = constrScreenSize;
        resolution = constrResolution;
        parseResolution(resolution);

        if(screenSize.equals("Fullscreen")) {
            setToFullscreen();
        }
        else {
            setToWindowed();
        }
    }

    public Background() {
        initComponents();
        setToFullscreen();
    }

    //Sets the size of the background to exactly the size of the screen
    public void setToFullscreen() {
        dispose();
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
    }

    public void setToWindowed() {
        dispose();
        setSize(width, height);
        setUndecorated(false);
    }

    public void parseResolution(String res) {
        Scanner scanRes = new Scanner(res).useDelimiter(" ");
        width = scanRes.nextInt();
        scanRes.next();
        height = scanRes.nextInt();
    }

    public void getDefaultRes() {
        Dimension screenDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        width = (int) screenDimension.getWidth();
        height = (int) screenDimension.getHeight();
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Background().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I then call the constructor of this in the **Settings class**

```
private void acceptSettingsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    new Background(screenSizeSettingComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), resolutionSettingComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()).setVisible(true);
}
```

Obviously this then creates a new instance of said Background class. Problem is, I'm now left with two instances of it, and I only want the new one.

What would be the easiest way of going about doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"I've been scouring the internet for an answer for ages now with no luck"* What is your question? Please [edit] to add a `?`.

Comment: A number of options.  Maintain a reference to the instance of `Background` which is been displayed and `dispose` of it when you need.  A better solution would be to have `Background` change size based on your needs, rather then having to create a new window from scratch

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to have Background change size without creating a new window each time, but I've found that the .setUndecorated() method requires disposing. Sorry for asking, but how would you "maintain a reference" to the instance of Background?